# Displaying parsed data to MainActivity from java class

Tags: java, android

```
 public void PrintRecordToResultTA() {
    int i = 0;
    Log.d("data","\nCodec: " + avlRecordCollection.getCodecID());
    Log.d("data","\nRecord Count: " + avlRecordCollection.getRecordCount());
```

I have used log to see if my program woks, but now I need to display this data on UI thread in MainActivity, this method was used to display data in java program, I was thinking should I recreate this class as Activity to reach data from another Activity to Main?
EDIT:

I have created ArrayList of AVL Records

```
public List<AVLRecord> avlRecords = new ArrayList<>();

public AVLRecordCollection CreateCollection() { // private
    return new AVLRecordCollection(codec, recordC, avlRecords);
}
```

And method to Create Records, which get all data I need to display... And I use avlRecord.add(AVLRecord) to pass all data.

```
 public void CreateRecord() {
    AVLRecord AVLRecord;
    RecordHeader recordHeader = GetRecord_Data();
    RecordGPS_Element recordGPS_element = GetRecord_GPS();
    RecordIO_Element recordIOElement = GetRecord_IO();
    AVLRecord = new AVLRecord(recordHeader, recordGPS_element, recordIOElement);
    avlRecords.add(AVLRecord);
}
```

Can someone give me an example how can I display data in MainActivity

Comment: How about you `return` some object rather than just Log it?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more so can better get your point? It's confusing right now.

Comment: @adnankhalil so I have data that has to be displayed in terminal(MainActivity) in textview probably, idk how can I return record collection in ui thread, the thing is passing data from class to MainActivity...

Answer (score 1):

If you are calling this method from `MainActivity` then you can use `return` to send back data to Activity class or can call a method to display with your data arrayList in Activity class.

To use `return` change your method return type from `void` to arraList of your data type.

```
public ArrayList<DataType> PrintRecordToResultTA() {

    ArrayList<DataType> avlRecordCollectionArray = new ArrayList<DataType>;
    // add data into avlRecordCollectionArray arraylist

    return avlRecordCollectionArray;
}
```

And in Activity class change method calling,

```
ArrayList<DataType> avlRecordCollectionArray = ClassName.PrintRecordToResultTA();
```

Then you will have arraylist of data in Activity class. Display data.

Comment: can you please look up for my post edit, Im probably doing something wrong